# Postgresql MD5 VS TRUST feature

Tags: postgresql

MD5 and TRUST Feature under pb_hba configuration file.which one to use and how does it change the login security in the application

Comment: Was there something missing in the documentation that didn’t explain enough of these?

Comment: It explains about TRUST allowing the user to login without a credential, where as MD5 requires password. I'm wondering if I'm missing something as the document didn't explain further

Comment: That’s pretty much it, except the methods used to do the password matching may also be of interest.